# Why aren't my images being displayed after logging in with different accounts?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve images and text from Firebase to my Recycle view and this works well. The only problem I'm experiencing is the images are not being loaded if I login with different phones but the text data are being loaded. Any help would be appreciated.

**Gets data from Firebase**

```
    //Retrieves information stored inside Post node...
    public void fetchUserInfo() {
        postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");
        postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    value = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                    postList.add(value);
                }
                adapter = new Adapter(Shop_Activity.this, postList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("Error", databaseError.toString());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**In this method I saved the necessary information inside a dictionary and uploaded it to Firebase**

```
 //saves user image and description inside firebase
    public void saveToFirebase(){
        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        postDictionary.put("desc", descriptionEditText.getText().toString());
        postDictionary.put("image", selectedImageUri.toString());
        postDictionary.put( "id",userId);
        productsDatabaseRef.child("Post").push().setValue(postDictionary);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Upload_Post.this, Shop_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> userPost;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> userPost){
        this.context = context;
        this.userPost = userPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.shop_layout_design,viewGroup, false));

    }

    //this is where you set the value for the ui elements
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.desc.setText(userPost.get(i).getdesc());

     Glide.with(this.context).load(userPost.get(i).getimage()).into(viewHolder.image);
//Picasso.get().load(userPost.get(i).getimage()).into(viewHolder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userPost.size();
    }


    //links up ui elements
    class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView desc;
        TextView id;
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are creating a new instance of the adapter each time you get the data from Firebase, there is no need to use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you set the adapter to your recyclerview :)

Comment: I removed that line from the code, but still the images are not being loaded after the app restarts.

Comment: Yes, that Will not.fix.the issue, is just to not use it if not necessary